# Is it possible to put transition between images changing with setInterval() function?

Tags: javascript, html, transition

Right now the images are only switching one by one, and I'm looking to add some kind of transition when images are changing for UX purposes.

In HTML it looks this:

```
<img id="image" src="img5.png" style="width:100%">
```

The script looks like this:

```
var imageSources = ["img1.png", "img2.png", "img3.png", "img4.png", "img5.png"]

var index = 0;
setInterval (function(){
  if (index === imageSources.length) {
    index = 0;
  }
  document.getElementById("image").src = imageSources[index];
    index++;
} , 2000);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate your question? It's unclear to me what you want to achieve.

Comment: @LajosArpad the thing I try to achieve is some kind of fade-out for previous img and fade-in for next

Comment: So the logical behavior is correct but you want some fade in/out animation for UX purposes?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have cooked up a solution for you:

```
<img id="myimage" src="http://www.dumpaday.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/1-45.jpg">
<script>
var images = [
    "http://www.dumpaday.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/1-45.jpg",
    "http://www.dumpaday.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/2-73.jpg",
    "http://www.dumpaday.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/3-66.jpg"
];
var index = 0;
var myImage = document.getElementById("myimage");
var i = 0;
setInterval(function() {
    if (++i % 2) {
        myImage.style.opacity = 0.1;
    } else {
        myImage.src = images[index = (index + 1) % images.length];
        myImage.style.opacity = 1;
    }
}, 2000);
</script>
<style>
    img {
      transition: opacity 1s;
    }
</style>
```

Note the styling.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m3rxwbdv/

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/4qox2d1p/4/

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .img {
            transition: 1s all;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script>
        const sources = [
        'http://placeimg.com/640/480/arch/1',
        'http://placeimg.com/640/480/arch/2',
        'http://placeimg.com/640/480/arch/3',
        'http://placeimg.com/640/480/arch/4',
        'http://placeimg.com/640/480/arch/5',
        ]
        const container = document.getElementById('container')
        const images = sources.map(source => {
          const img = document.createElement('img')
          img.style.opacity = 0;
          img.style.position = 'absolute'
          img.classList.add('img')
          img.src = source
          container.appendChild(img)
          return img
        })

        images[0].style.opacity = 1
        let current = 0
        setInterval(() => {
          images.forEach((image, index) => {
            image.style.opacity = index === current ? 1 : 0
          })
          current++
          if (current > sources.length - 1) current = 0
        }, 1000)

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```